# Kubernetes Installation with Vagrant & CoreOS behind proxy

Tags: vagrant, kubernetes, coreos

I am behind a proxy server and following the "Kubernetes Installation with Vagrant & CoreOS" steps listed here: https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubernetes-on-vagrant.html

After finalizing the install, when I run

```
$ kubectl get nodes
```

I get the error.

```
Unable to connect to the server: Service Unavailable
```

e1, c1, and w1 are up and I can issue $vagrant ssh each of them.

when I check the w1, I have seen docker service was not running with the error listed below.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
--
-- The result is dependency.
Aug 19 04:09:25 w1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Job docker.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Aug 19 04:09:25 w1 systemd[1]: flanneld.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 19 04:09:25 w1 systemd[1]: flanneld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 19 04:09:30 w1 systemd[1]: flanneld.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 19 04:09:30 w1 systemd[1]: Stopped Network fabric for containers.
-- Subject: Unit flanneld.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit flanneld.service has finished shutting down.
Aug 19 04:09:30 w1 systemd[1]: Starting Network fabric for containers...
-- Subject: Unit flanneld.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit flanneld.service has begun starting up.
Aug 19 04:09:30 w1 rkt[6888]: image: using image from file /usr/lib/rkt/stage1-images/stage1-fly.aci
Aug 19 04:09:31 w1 rkt[6888]: image: searching for app image quay.io/coreos/flannel
Aug 19 04:09:31 w1 rkt[6888]: run: discovery failed
Aug 19 04:09:31 w1 systemd[1]: flanneld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 19 04:09:31 w1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Network fabric for containers.
-- Subject: Unit flanneld.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit flanneld.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Aug 19 04:09:31 w1 systemd[1]: flanneld.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 19 04:09:31 w1 systemd[1]: flanneld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am guessing that problem is because of I am behind the proxy. Before running the install steps I issue the commands

```
$export "HTTP_PROXY=http://http-proxy.xxxxxx.com:8080"
$export "HTTPS_PROXY=http://http-proxy.xxxxxx.com:8080"
$export "http_proxy=http://http-proxy.xxxxxx.com:8080"
$export "https_proxy=http://http-proxy.xxxxxx.com:8080"
```

Do you know if this is enough for the installation behind proxy or do I need to add proxy settings to somewhere else.

Thank you in advance,
turgos

Answer (score 1):

The variables you're exporting are valid only in your current shell session, they are not available to your flannel systemd unit.

Create the following drop-in inside the systemd unit directory, and then reload the daemon with `systemctl daemon-reload`, it should fix your issue with flannel:

`/etc/systemd/system/flannel.service.d/proxy.conf`:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://http-proxy.xxx:8080"
Environment="...
```

A similar example is available in the CoreOS documentation: [Customizing Docker](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/customizing-docker.html#use-an-http-proxy)

Comment: Yes, that helped to fix the flannel issue and I can see the Docker running on all 3 machines e1, c1 and w1. But I still get the "Unable to connect to the server: Service Unavailable" reply when I make the "$ kubectl get nodes" call. Is there any Kubernetes log somewhere to diagnose the problem?

Comment: It depends how your API server was started, also as a systemd unit? In that case try `journalctl -u kube-apiserver`. Inside a container (rkt, Docker)? Then simply check the logs of that particular container.

Comment: This documentation page may help you if your kubernetes components are running inside a rkt container (which seems to be the case in your setup): https://coreos.com/rkt/docs/latest/commands.html#logging